# Is there an example of "unfindable" interaction function?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, roots, fixed-point-iteration

In Numerical Analysis, the problem of finding an approximation for a root of an equation
$$
f(x)=0
$$
may be solved using Fixed Point Iteration (refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration ). To use this method, one must write the previous equation
as
$$
x=F(x)
$$
($F$ is called an iteration function) and, if $f$ (which can be assumed to be differentiable) has a single root $\xi$ around an interval $(a,b)$, the sequence
$$
x_{k+1}=F(x_k),k=0,1,2,...
$$
converges to $\xi$ as long as $|F'(x)|<1$ in a small interval around $\xi$ in which the initial step $x_0$ is taken.

Now, given some equation $f(x)=0$, one can find several ways to write it as $x=F(x)$. As I discussed this matter with some of my students, I wondered if there was a way to guarantee that there is always a suitable $F$ (that is, $|F_1(x)|<1$ around $\xi$), given any $f(x)=0$. Of course, if there was some example in which this is impossible, then the question would also be answered.